# Are there any Clojure libraries for p2p?

Tags: clojure, p2p

I'm a web developer, but lately I have been learning Clojure and now I'm interested in creating a p2p application. And since Clojure is a general purpose language, I guess I can just use that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your running Clojure on the JVM, [something like Pastry?](http://www.freepastry.org/)

We can't help you much since you haven't given us much to work with, so have you done a general search for "Java p2p"? What have you tried already?

Note that p2p is quite complex with lots of non-trivial problems like bypassing firewall's and NATs. I would start with a client-server architecture first and only go to p2p when its impossible to scale the server further

Answer (score 1):

Below are a couple links I just found:

- Mist helps building distributed services by offering a UDP multiplexer, a Kademlia overlay and a simple pubsub protocol. At least that's what this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jamii/1910754) says, and the code should be on [github](https://github.com/jamii/mist).
- [Nightweb](http://nightweb.net/) can help building P2P apps on Android, and could be at least an inspiration.

As I said I just found these on the net, I never used any of these and don't even know how useful/usable these are. Also, this is not really an answer but this [resource page on P2P](http://lifeisagraph.net/p2p.html) created by a clojure programmer might be of interest.